# Converting glsl shaders

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl

I need to convert these shaders from #version 400 core to #version 130 successfully but for some reason when I do it my models are not rendering properly when I load more then one type and I cant find any other issues with my code

Version 400 (vertexShader):

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

uniform float useFakeLighting;
uniform vec2 offset;

const float density = 0.004;
const float gradient = 1.5;

void main(void) {

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCam;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    vec3 actualNormal = normal;
    if(useFakeLighting > 0.5) {
        actualNormal = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(actualNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
    toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

    float distance = length(positionRelativeToCam.xyz);
    visibility = exp(-pow((distance * density), gradient));
    visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

and heres my version 130 vertexShader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;
out float visibility;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

uniform float useFakeLighting;
uniform vec2 offset;

const float density = 0.004;
const float gradient = 1.5;

void main(void) {

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCam = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCam;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    vec3 actualNormal = normal;
    if(useFakeLighting > 0.5) {
        actualNormal = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(actualNormal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
    toCameraVector = (transpose(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

    float distance = length(positionRelativeToCam.xyz);
    visibility = exp(-pow((distance * density), gradient));
    visibility = clamp(visibility, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

I swapped out the inverse for transpose as its not supported in glsl 130 apparently. Theres also a small change in the fragment shaders as below:
Core 400 version fragment:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in float visibility;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;
uniform vec3 skyColour;

void main(void) {

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDot1, 0.2);
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
    vec3 finalSpecular = dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour;
    vec4 textureColour = texture(modelTexture, pass_textureCoords);

    if(textureColour.a < 0.5) {
        discard;
    }

    out_Color = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * textureColour + vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);
    out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), out_Color, visibility);

}
```

and the 130 version:

```
#version 130

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;
in float visibility;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity;
uniform vec3 skyColour;

void main(void) {

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDot1, 0.2);
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
    vec3 finalSpecular = dampedFactor * reflectivity * lightColour;
    vec4 textureColour = texture2D(modelTexture, pass_textureCoords);

    if(textureColour.a < 0.5) {
        discard;
    }

    out_Color = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * textureColour + vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);
    out_Color = mix(vec4(skyColour, 1.0), out_Color, visibility);

}
```

You can't use texture in the 130 core so I used texture2d and it works fine when I am loading only one model type but when I add the other models, they lose vertex positions and I am not sure as to why so i want to make sure these are converted properly. Thanks in advance.